# Problem based on sylow theorem

Tags: sylow-theory

Let G be a group of order 3179. (a) State the orders of the Sylow p-subgroups of G. (b) Use the Sylow Theorems to determine the possible answers to the question: "How many Sylow p-subgroups can G have?'

Comment: Please show the own attempts to solve the issue, it is the way it works. At least the factorization of $3179$ should be there as minimal effort under the minimal efforts...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $3179=11 \cdot 17^2$ and $11 \not\equiv 1$ mod $17$ and $17 \not\equiv 1$ mod $11$ and $17^2 \not\equiv 1$ mod $11$. What can you conclude for $\#Syl_{11}(G)$ and $\#Syl_{17}(G)$?